# Unable to install awscli because of httpsession not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I am following the official documentation in order to install aws-cli on my Ubuntu.

However, pip installation is successful but when I run the command:

```
 sudo pip install awscli --upgrade --user
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aviral/.local/bin/aws", line 27, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/aviral/.local/bin/aws", line 23, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 58, in main
    driver = create_clidriver()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 68, in create_clidriver
    event_hooks=session.get_component('event_emitter'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/awscli/plugin.py", line 44, in load_plugins
    modules = _import_plugins(plugin_mapping)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/awscli/plugin.py", line 61, in _import_plugins
    module = __import__(path, fromlist=[module])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/awscli/handlers.py", line 20, in <module>
    from awscli.paramfile import register_uri_param_handler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/awscli/paramfile.py", line 18, in <module>
    from botocore.httpsession import URLLib3Session
ImportError: No module named 'botocore.httpsession
```

My Python is:
`/usr/local/bin/python`
And my aws is:
`/home/aviral/.local/bin/aws`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running this command:

```
sudo pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade --ignore-installed
```

Similar issue is answered here: [ImportError](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429717/importerror-no-module-named-botocore-session-when-running-aws-cli-from-rundec/430022#430022)

Edit:

Previous command:

```
pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade
```

Comment: i got the following errors:
`airflow 1.8.0 has requirement lxml<4.0,>=3.6.0, but you'll have lxml 3.5.0 which is incompatible.
feedshark 0.0.2 has requirement python-dateutil==2.5.3, but you'll have python-dateutil 2.7.5 which is incompatible.
feedshark 0.0.2 has requirement requests==2.11.1, but you'll have requests 2.9.1 which is incompatible.
Cannot uninstall 'docutils'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`

Comment: I got it
I ran the command: `sudo pip install awscli --force-reinstall --upgrade --ignore-installed` and it's installed!

Comment: please include my above comment so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: @aviralsanjay: Done.